# Dict support in PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

Does PyTorch support *dict*-like objects, through which we can backpropagate gradients, like *Tensors* in PyTorch?

My goal is to compute gradients with respect to a few (1%) elements of a large matrix. But if I use PyTorch's standard *Tensors* to store the matrix, I need to keep the whole matrix in my GPU, which causes problems due to limited GPU memory available during training. So I was thinking whether I could store the matrix as a *dict* instead, indexing only the relevant elements of the matrix, and computing gradients and backpropagating w.r.t those select elements only.

So far, I have tried using *Tensors* only, but it's causing memory issues for the above reasons. So I searched extensively for alternate options like *dicts* in PyTorch but couldn't find any such information on Google.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want your parameter to be a [`torch.sparse`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html) tensor.
This interface allows you to have tensors that are mostly zeros, with only a few non-zero elements *in known locations*. Sparse tensors should allow you to significantly reduce the memory footprint of your model.
Note that this interface is still "under construction": not all operations are supported for sparse tensors. However, it is being constantly improving.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I will try using `torch.sparse` and will update here.

Comment: I tried using `torch.sparse_coo_tensor` for this, and it does require less space than the full matrix, but unfortunately it seems it doesn't support most of the operations that I need to perform on it. Thanks for the suggestion though!